# What's the lifetime of temporary objects in a range-for?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, temporary-objects

Consider this class:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    ~ Foo ()
    {
        std::cout << "~Foo\n";
    }

    typedef std::vector<std::string> Words;

    const Words & words ()
    {
        return m_words;
    }

private:

    Words m_words = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
};
```

Section 12.2 of the C++ standard specifies lifetimes of temporary objects. I thought this would be okay:

```
for (auto w : Foo () .words ())
    std::cout << w << "\n";
```

But it wasn't

```
~Foo
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
[1]    10290 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

The standard is confusing me. Why is `~Foo` being called before the loop runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current standard says in **The range-based for statement [stmt.ranged]** that

> The range-based for statement
>   `for ( init-statementopt for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer )` statement
>   is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     init-statementopt
>     auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
>     auto __begin = begin-expr ;
>     auto __end = end-expr ;
>     for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
>       for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>       statement
>     }
> }
> ```

This means that your `Foo().words()` is only used in the assignment `auto  &&__range = Foo().words();` and that the temporary object not lives until the code reaches the for loop.

Please note that I copied from the [latest C++20 draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4791.pdf). In C++11 the code is a bit different, but the relevant part is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is to be found in the way the [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Explanation) is defined and to what `__range` is bound to.

> **[[class.temporary]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6)** - There are three contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression.
>
> - The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary object. The temporary object to which the reference is bound **or the temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference** ...

If you change the `for-loop` expression to bind directly to the subobject `m_words`(assuming that it were public), then the lifetime of `Foo()` will be extended and the following will work

```
for (auto w : Foo ().m_words)
    std::cout << w << "\n";
```